PHP in Wordpress doesn't loop through every row
I have the following snippet:
if ($listings->have_posts()) {
    while ($listings->have_posts()) : $listings->the_post();
        if (have_rows('ticket_group')) :
            $ticket_group_count = count(get_field('ticket_group'));
            echo "<br>Number of ticket_groups: $ticket_group_count<br>";
            while (have_rows('ticket_group')) : the_row();
                echo 'Checking ticket_group...<br>';
            endwhile;
        endif;
    endwhile;
}

On one page it shows me:
Number of ticket_groups: 3
Checking ticket_group...
Checking ticket_group...
Checking ticket_group...

Which is what I would expect given it says there are three ticket groups. However, on another, it shows me the following i.e. only one record, but there are three in total
Number of ticket_groups: 3
Checking ticket_group...

I am using the advanced custom fields plugin, but I can't see how that would cause this issue.
Any suggestions on how to further debug?
The loop was quite large before so I have trimmed it down to the basics and it's still happening.
I added a print_r of get_field('ticket_group') and got the following which suggests there are indeed three items:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ticket_group_name] => Coach Travel (Weekend Return)
            [ticket_group_start] => 
            [ticket_group_finish] => 
            [ticket_group_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [package_name] => Return Coach Travel - Thursday arrival, Monday return
                            [package_object] => WP_Post Object
                                (
                                    [ID] => 2164
                                    [post_author] => 7991
                                    [post_date] => 2023-12-13 19:59:58
                                    [post_date_gmt] => 2023-12-13 19:59:58
                                    [post_content] => ...
                                    [post_title] => BLOODSTOCK 2024 - THURSDAY ARRIVAL - MONDAY ARRIVAL - RETURN COACH TRAVEL
                                    [post_excerpt] => 
                                    [post_status] => publish
                                    [comment_status] => closed
                                    [ping_status] => closed
                                    [post_password] => 
                                    [post_name] => bloodstock-2024-thursday-arrival-monday-arrival-return-coach-travel
                                    [to_ping] => 
                                    [pinged] => 
                                    [post_modified] => 2024-04-30 17:03:25
                                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2024-04-30 16:03:25
                                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                                    [post_parent] => 0
                                    [guid] => https://biggreencoach.co.uk/package/bloodstock-2024-thursday-arrival-monday-arrival-return-coach-travel/
                                    [menu_order] => 0
                                    [post_type] => package
                                    [post_mime_type] => 
                                    [comment_count] => 0
                                    [filter] => raw
                                )

                            [package_start_date] => 01/01/2024 12:00 am
                            [package_end_date] => 13/08/2024 12:00 pm
                            [package_on_sale_date] => 2024-02-06 11:00
                            [package_type] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Weekend
                                    [1] => Return
                                    [2] => Coach
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ticket_group_name] => Weekend Festival Ticket + Coach Travel Package
            [ticket_group_start] => 
            [ticket_group_finish] => 
            [ticket_group_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [package_name] => Weekend Camping Ticket + Return Coach - Thursday arrival, Monday return
                            [package_object] => WP_Post Object
                                (
                                    [ID] => 2165
                                    [post_author] => 7991
                                    [post_date] => 2023-12-13 19:59:58
                                    [post_date_gmt] => 2023-12-13 19:59:58
                                    [post_content] => ...
                                    [post_title] => BLOODSTOCK 2024 - THURSDAY ARRIVAL - MONDAY DEPARTURE - RETURN COACH TRAVEL + FESTIVAL TICKET
                                    [post_excerpt] => 
                                    [post_status] => publish
                                    [comment_status] => closed
                                    [ping_status] => closed
                                    [post_password] => 
                                    [post_name] => bloodstock-2024-thursday-arrival-monday-departure-return-coach-travel-festival-ticket
                                    [to_ping] => 
                                    [pinged] => 
                                    [post_modified] => 2023-12-13 19:59:58
                                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2023-12-13 19:59:58
                                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                                    [post_parent] => 0
                                    [guid] => https://biggreencoach.co.uk/package/bloodstock-2024-thursday-arrival-monday-departure-return-coach-travel-festival-ticket/
                                    [menu_order] => 0
                                    [post_type] => package
                                    [post_mime_type] => 
                                    [comment_count] => 0
                                    [filter] => raw
                                )

                            [package_start_date] => 01/01/2024 12:00 am
                            [package_end_date] => 13/08/2024 12:00 pm
                            [package_on_sale_date] => 2024-01-03 00:00
                            [package_type] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Weekend
                                    [1] => Return
                                    [2] => Coach
                                    [3] => Festival Ticket
                                    [4] => Camping
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ticket_group_name] => Shuttle Bus (Weekend Return)
            [ticket_group_start] => 
            [ticket_group_finish] => 
            [ticket_group_details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [package_name] => Shuttle Bus - Thursday arrival, Monday return
                            [package_object] => WP_Post Object
                                (
                                    [ID] => 3864
                                    [post_author] => 7991
                                    [post_date] => 2024-01-26 10:43:53
                                    [post_date_gmt] => 2024-01-26 10:43:53
                                    [post_content] => ...
                                    [post_title] => BLOODSTOCK 2024 - SHUTTLE SERVICE
                                    [post_excerpt] => 
                                    [post_status] => publish
                                    [comment_status] => closed
                                    [ping_status] => closed
                                    [post_password] => 
                                    [post_name] => bloodstock-2024-shuttle-service
                                    [to_ping] => 
                                    [pinged] => 
                                    [post_modified] => 2024-04-30 17:04:08
                                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2024-04-30 16:04:08
                                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                                    [post_parent] => 0
                                    [guid] => https://biggreencoach.co.uk/package/bloodstock-2024-shuttle-service/
                                    [menu_order] => 0
                                    [post_type] => package
                                    [post_mime_type] => 
                                    [comment_count] => 0
                                    [filter] => raw
                                )

                            [package_start_date] => 01/01/2024 12:00 am
                            [package_end_date] => 13/08/2024 12:00 pm
                            [package_on_sale_date] => 2024-01-03 00:00
                            [package_type] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Weekend
                                    [1] => Return
                                    [2] => Shuttle
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)


Are you sure, that the_row() is definitively not called twice in your code somewhere? The symptoms sound a bit like this one: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/what-does-the_row-return/

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/ suggests it can be used multiple times, just not twice within the same loop
